# Largest eigenvalues distribution of tridiagonal symmetric random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, random-matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory

I would like to find the largest eigenvalue distribution of the following tridiagonal symmetric random matrix in an analytic way.

All the ${\lambda}_i$ are distributed the same way with chi-square (but any other real positive distribution will be OK if it helps)

\begin{align}
 \small
%%%%%
                M := \begin{bmatrix}
%%
 0 &  \lambda_1^{-1/2}   & 0 &0 & \dots &0&0 \\
%%
\lambda_1^{-1/2} & 0  & \lambda_2^{-1/2}   & 0  & \dots &0&0 \\
%%
 0& \lambda_2^{-1/2} & 0 &  \lambda_3^{-1/2}    & \dots &0&0 \\
%%%
 & &&\vdots \\
%%%
 0& 0 & 0 & \dots &\lambda_{n-1}^{-1/2}  & 0& \lambda_{n }^{-1/2}     \\
%%%
 0& 0 & 0 & \dots &0 & \lambda_{n }^{-1/2}  & 0
%%%
 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Although Sturm sequences seems to be a good fit for this issue, I couldn’t solve the integral for any positive distribution when ${n>2}$

Comment: why is it "skew"?

Comment: All the main diagonal values are zeros

Comment: To me a Skew-symmetric matrix has $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$ which is not the case here. Here it is just a usual symmetric matrix with zero diagonal...

Comment: Alright, I’ve removed the skew remark, you might be right